# Renewing AWS AssumeRoleRequest on expiry

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have the following for assuming role credentials for my lambda client:

```
    AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient stsClient = new AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient(credentials);
    AssumeRoleRequest assumeRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
            .withRoleArn(config.getAssumeLambdaARN())
            .withDurationSeconds(3600)
            .withRoleSessionName("AssumeRoleTest");

    AssumeRoleResult assumeResult = stsClient.assumeRole(assumeRequest);
    BasicSessionCredentials temporaryCredentials =
            new BasicSessionCredentials(
                    assumeResult.getCredentials().getAccessKeyId(),
                    assumeResult.getCredentials().getSecretAccessKey(),
                    assumeResult.getCredentials().getSessionToken());
    AWSLambdaClientBuilder lambdaClientBuilder = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard();
    lambdaClientBuilder.setCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(temporaryCredentials));
    lambdaClientBuilder.setRegion(config.getAwsRegion());

    lambdaClient = lambdaClientBuilder.build();
```

`AssumeRoleRequest` is going to expire after `1hr`. How do I automatically create another assumeRequest and re-create the `lambdaClient` when the request is expired?

Comment: Lambda cannot run over 300 seconds, shouldn't it obtain new STS for every execution cycle?

Comment: @Greyeye Should I not use the same STS until it expires, and then renew it?

Comment: lambda is stateless
1 not sure if you can **keep** any state. 
2 If you're to keep a whole STS, **MAYBE(?)** to consider assuming role on the higher level and delegate it to lower level lamda? (eg use AWS Step function)